# How to limit the max chunk size for chunked_transfer_encoding in nginx?

Tags: http, nginx, server, backend, nginx-config

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to limit the chunk size, as in, the maximum size a response body can have for an nginx v1.19.7.

#### What I tried

I found various parameters that do similar things in the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_buffer_size), among them `client_body_buffer_size`.

> Sets buffer size for reading client request body. In case the request body is larger than the buffer, the whole body or only its part is written to a temporary file. By default, buffer size is equal to two memory pages. This is 8K on x86, other 32-bit platforms, and x86-64. It is usually 16K on other 64-bit platforms.

Which does not sound like it's limiting the size of response chunks, but rather how buffer size for incoming packages with any kind chunk size.

Similarly i can configure: `chunked_transfer_encoding` which the docs say is

> Allows disabling chunked transfer encoding in HTTP/1.1. It may come in handy when using a software failing to support chunked encoding despite the standard’s requirement.

This sounds like it's disabling the chunked transfer, but I have not found the configuration option to limit the chunk size for the chunked transfer.

Which parameter am I missing?

**Edit:**

[I found the HTTP/2 parameter `http2_chunk_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html) but I'm unsure if it's related.

> Sets the maximum size of chunks into which the response body is sliced. A too low value results in higher overhead. A too high value impairs prioritization due to HOL blocking.

it sounds like it, but I'm not sure. It was added in v1.9.5.

Comment: `client_body_max_size` is what i usually set. If you use PHP, you have to set corresponding limit and timeout in PHP too.

Comment: docs say this about the server reading the client request body. I want to limit the response body size from the server to the client, so basically the other way around.

Comment: I'm curious, what's your use case?

Comment: Benchmarking it against a server that can do this